# I need help using an array with a class

Tags: c++

I get an error " undefined reference to 'Card::Card()' ", when I try to compile. This program is supposed to print all cards in a deck after I initialize each one. It has to use OOP so I don't need that changed. Help anyone!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

class Card
{

private:
string suit;
string value;

public:
    Card();

    Card(string a, string b)
    {
        suit = a;
        value = b;
    }

    string getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }

    string getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    void print()
    {
        cout << getSuit() << " of " << getValue() << endl;
    }

};


int main()
{
    Card cardlist[52];

    cardlist[0] = Card("2","Spades");
    cardlist[1] = Card("3","Spades");
    cardlist[2] = Card("4","Spades");
    cardlist[3] = Card("5","Spades");
    cardlist[4] = Card("6","Spades");
    cardlist[5] = Card("7","Spades");
    cardlist[6] = Card("8","Spades");
    cardlist[7] = Card("9","Spades");
    cardlist[8] = Card("10","Spades");
    cardlist[9] = Card("Jack","Spades");
    cardlist[10] = Card("Queen","Spades");
    cardlist[11] = Card("King","Spades");
    cardlist[12] = Card("Ace","Spades");
    cardlist[13] = Card("2","Hearts");
    cardlist[14] = Card("3","Hearts");
    cardlist[15] = Card("4","Hearts");
    cardlist[16] = Card("5","Hearts");
    cardlist[17] = Card("6","Hearts");
    cardlist[18] = Card("7","Hearts");
    cardlist[19] = Card("8","Hearts");
    cardlist[20] = Card("9","Hearts");
    cardlist[21] = Card("10","Hearts");
    cardlist[22] = Card("Jack","Hearts");
    cardlist[23] = Card("Queen","Hearts");
    cardlist[24] = Card("King","Hearts");
    cardlist[25] = Card("Ace","Hearts");
    cardlist[26] = Card("2","Diamonds");
    cardlist[27] = Card("3","Diamonds");
    cardlist[28] = Card("4","Diamonds");
    cardlist[29] = Card("5","Diamonds");
    cardlist[30] = Card("6","Diamonds");
    cardlist[31] = Card("7","Diamonds");
    cardlist[32] = Card("8","Diamonds");
    cardlist[33] = Card("9","Diamonds");
    cardlist[34] = Card("10","Diamonds");
    cardlist[35] = Card("Jack","Diamonds");
    cardlist[36] = Card("Queen","Diamonds");
    cardlist[37] = Card("King","Diamonds");
    cardlist[38] = Card("Ace","Diamonds");
    cardlist[39] = Card("2","Clubs");
    cardlist[40] = Card("3","Clubs");
    cardlist[41] = Card("4","Clubs");
    cardlist[42] = Card("5","Clubs");
    cardlist[43] = Card("6","Clubs");
    cardlist[44] = Card("7","Clubs");
    cardlist[45] = Card("8","Clubs");
    cardlist[46] = Card("9","Clubs");
    cardlist[47] = Card("10","Clubs");
    cardlist[48] = Card("Jack","Clubs");
    cardlist[49] = Card("Queen","Clubs");
    cardlist[50] = Card("King","Clubs");
    cardlist[51] = Card("Ace","Clubs");

    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        cardlist[i].print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new Card("2", "Diamonds")` Notice `new`

Comment: Only reason i added ctime is because i will need it later on and forgot to take it out for this post.

Comment: did you define Card::Card somewhere and linked the corresponding module correctly? @jnbbender why using 'new'?

Comment: `Card cardlist[52]` calls the default constructor for (52 times) to create the objects in the array. Note: this is an array of objects, not object *references* (as it would be in Java).

Comment: @The Techel, I didnt do that no but im not sure how to

Comment: Because you've only declared an array of `Card`'s, now you have to allocate them.  That is how you dynamically do it.  If you want to statically allocate them you have to do it when you declare the array.

Comment: There is no definition for constructor `Card();`, which is used by `Card cardlist[52];` to default construct the array items.

Comment: are you using a IDE like VisualStudio or CodeBlocks? Make sure the file with the definition of the Car-Class' contructor is within the project.

Comment: i'm using CodeBlocks, i did this on visual studio in class earlier and it worked fine albeit with different array values.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can delete everything in main except "Card cardlist[52];" and still get the error.  You incorrectly assume that you create cards only when you have a suit and value.  Although you could initialize this array with braces, and thus avoid ever creating a default card with no suit/value.  (Also your suit and value are reversed.)

Comment: @BradyHamby Where is the code for `Card()`?  That is the bottom line as to why you are getting the linker error.  Also, you could have used a simple loop [like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e52b0a24dc5acac7) to initialize the cards instead of wearing out your keyboard, your eyes, and your fingers typing in 52 lines of initialization code.

Answer (score 0):

You define that a default constructor exists, but you don't define it:

```
    Card();
```

if you don't need or want a constructor, you can use the default one that the compiler can generate for you:

```
    Card() = default;
```

Or simply delete that line. your code will work then.

your error is **just** that.

Comment: Thanks guys, I used @Tomaz Canabrava solution and it worked. The reason I have the default constructor method is because the assignment calls for it and i'll lose points without it. I got it working.

Comment: @Tomaz Since he defines a parameterized constructor, the default one is no longer implicitly available. When he declares the array, all elements are initialized using the default constructor, which must exist. Declaring one as default will be remedial, but removing the declaration all together will produce another error due to no default being available, versus one being undefined but declared.